# Added click event to span tag and its getting called twice from namespace

Tags: javascript, javascript-namespaces

I do have a span tag that I added a click event to and it gets called twice even though I only click it once and I have no idea why. If I run this code in a separate project then the button only gets called once, but when I bring it into a working project then click events are happening twice.

I am using a namespace for my code

and here is the code

the HTML

```
<span type="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Save" class="" id="btnSaveWindow"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>
<span type="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Remove Item" class="" id="btnRemoveFromItemsGrid"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>
<span type="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Close" class="" id="btnClosePromptDialog"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></span>
```

And here is the javascript

```
var ItemsGrid = ItemsGrid || {};
ItemsGrid.Prompts = ItemsGrid.Prompts || {};

ItemsGrid.Prompts = {
    AddButtonEventsForPrompts: function () {
        $('#btnRemoveFromItemsGrid').on('click', () => { 
            this.DeleteItemOrAttachment("2");
        });

        $('#btnClosePromptDialog').on('click', () => {
            this.ClosePrompt();
        });
    },
    ClosePrompt: function () 
        $('#SiteOverlayFullScreen').css('display', 'none');
        $('#PromptsDialog').css('display', 'none');
    },
    DeleteItemOrAttachment: function (deleteItemKey) {
        this.DeleteItemOrAttachment_Success(deleteItemKey);
    },
    DeleteItemOrAttachment_Success: function (deleteItemKey) {       
        this.DeleteItemOrAttachment_Success(deleteItemKey);
    }
}
```

Comment: If it only happens in certain contexts, my guess is that either you **1)** are calling the script that sets the even handlers twice somehow, or **2)** you have accidentally duplicated some code that adds identical event handlers.  Is it possible for you to update the code provided as an [mcve] in a snippet?  The code provided is useful, but we don't see where you actually call `AddButtonEventsForPrompts`.  You could also just but a `debugger` statement inside that function and see how many times it is called, and from where.

Comment: @AlexanderNied, your comment let me find where the issue is, its where I am calling AdvanceWare.ItemsGrid.Prompts.AddButtonEventsForPrompts(), I removed it out of where it was placed and now the events are not getting hit twice

Comment: Excellent, glad to here you were able to resolve your issue!